# Any way to force a workspace run only once

Tags: fme

I have a legacy FME script written a long back but now I got a scenario to add a new workspace and call it only once. If I am running this script manually then it triggers only once but the moment I run all workspace together then running twice.

Just curious to know is there any way to force the workspace to trigger only once irrespective of input count. I have attached the screenshot below to give more clarity.

[image]

As you can see this stacked_linker_workspace wanna trigger once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add `counter` and `tester` transformer just before `Stacked_Linker_workspace`
On the tester, create test to pass when the value of counter is the first number (by default it's 0)
[image]